# Recursive Binary Search in Typescript

Tags: typescript, binary-search

I've ran a few tests, not extensive though, and it apparently works. Like many standard binary search algorithms, if the number returned is < 0, you can take the complement (~) of the returned value to find the insert point, eg `const ix = bs(arr, 5); // ~ix is the insertion point`

````
interface bsRange {
    min: number;
    max: number;
}

const bs = (arr: number[], value: number, range: bsRange | null = null): number => {
    if (!range) range = {
        min: 0, max: arr.length - 1
    };

    const indexToCheck = Math.floor((range.min + range.max) / 2);
    const iValue = arr[indexToCheck];
    if (value === iValue) return indexToCheck;

    if (range.max === range.min) {
        // we're at the last element to check
        if (iValue > value) {
            return ~(range.max);
        } else {
            return ~(range.max) - 1;
        }
    }


    if (value < iValue) {
        range.max = indexToCheck - 1;
    } else if (value > iValue) {
        range.min = indexToCheck + 1;
    }

    return bs(arr, value, range);
};
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks good to me. I just stumbled over the `range` parameter, which feels unusual to me. But if you remove it, you have to combine the result for the upper half of the considered array.

```
const bs = (arr: number[], value: number): number => {
    const indexToCheck = Math.floor((arr.length - 1) / 2);
    const iValue = arr[indexToCheck];

    if (value === iValue) return indexToCheck;
    if (arr.length === 1) return (iValue > value) ? ~0 : ~1;
    if (value < iValue) return bs(arr.slice(0, indexToCheck), value)

    const subResult = bs(arr.slice(indexToCheck + 1), value);
    return subResult >= 0
        ? indexToCheck + 1 + subResult
        : ~(indexToCheck + 1 + ~subResult)
};
```

Comment: I suppose for me, it's one of those variables that helps me mentally keep track of what's actually going on.